# Custom domain for github project pages

Tags: github

I have a custom domain name (www.example.com) pointing to my github user page (user.github.com). Is it possible to have a second custom domain name like www.newdomain.com pointing to a project page of the same github account (user.github.com/project)?

I was able to correctly set up the CNAME in the gh-page branch of user.github.com/project, but I seem not able to correctly set up the DNS on my domain name provider (he seems not to like the subfolder /project).

Thanks a lot for all the help you can  provide me!

Answer (score 5):

Actually I solved the issue... 
I had to point the DNS only to my main github user name.  The CNAME in the gh-page branch of user.github.com/project took care of the rest and now www.newdomain.com correctly points to user.github.com/project while www.example.com points to (user.github.com