# How to publish GitHub Pages projects on different Domain Names

Tags: vue.js, github, dns, github-pages, cname

I want to publish my root **username.github.io** repo on a domain **myname.ca** (nikolakuzmic.ca) and a separate repo **vue-helloworld-ghpages** on a **Different domain** name (mynextmovie.ca).

So far, I was only able to properly publish my root repo on nikolakuzmic.ca domain.

For the custom project, inside vue-helloworld-ghpages [repo](https://github.com/kuzmicni/vue-helloworld-ghpages), on gh-pages branch, I added a CNAME file to point to mynextmovie.ca.
On GoDaddy side, I added the 4 Github IPs (185.199.108-11.153) as 'A records' and a CNAME pointing to my root GitHub username (kuzmicni.github.io) as suggested in these 2 posts ([Custom domain for github project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384498/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages), [Custom domain for GitHub project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages)) but the website is not loaded properly and only an empty page is displayed:

[image]

However, if I just publish the custom project by default it goes to nikolakuzmic.ca/vue-helloworld-ghpages and the content is loaded properly
[image]

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to solve the issue, you have to leave `publicPath` in the `vue.config.js` file empty like this

```
module.exports = {
}
```

instead of having

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath:'/REPO_NAME/'
}
```